# VBA copy data from one workbook sheet to another workbook sheet

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

The data above is given to my company every month.

[image]

the data here is just me copy and pasting each and every data to this workbook every month manually.

Notice that they do tally. For example, Available for sales security tallies with each other in terms of value. My question is how do I write a macro to solve this in a automated manner? Can someone point me in a direction to get started. My manager just asked me to try to automate this process to save time. Im thinking of storing the values in variables for the first image and inserting the value in certain cells if the variable names are the same for the next workbook. is that possible? Please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by VBA however I think it would be using sledgehammer to crack a walnut.

Instead you can use vlookup or Index(Match()) combo which is comparative easier to use.

you are looking at creating a "master" file one sheet your version and second sheet you can copy data when you receive it.

In you sheet you will need to apply one of the above mention formula linking to second worksheet.

By the way this what I think is best approach. if you still want to use VBA please post you code or research so far to get more specific help.